# Bootstrap Side Nav issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with the Twitter Bootstrap template. At http://www.tjprizbiz.com/new/publications.html, I am trying to have my side bar nav jump to each different project, but since all my projects are contained in a `span9`, anytime I click a side nav bar option it just goes to the top of my container span9 projects column. I know I need to fix my `href` of the sidebar nav buttons but I don't know how to make it search within the `span9` section id's. Any Ideas?

PS: I cant get my code to paste but you can get the page source @ www.tjprizbiz.com/new/publications.html

Comment: You need to probably use ScrollSpy and Affix: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html

Comment: It was working fine until I contained all of my projects in a span 9. Therefore I'm not sure this is the issue. Just wondering if there was maybe and extension I could put to the href, such as "#span9/#'projectname'" but i know this isn't possible.

Comment: It seems to be working for the first two sections...?

Comment: Adam D, ACtually, my apologies. I hadn't pushed the most recent save. Amateur hour over here. Should be current now... Sorry.